# Grab only XML content from a returned data

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

Im completely stuck on how to approach this. Basically i have a curl call that returns a xml along with other info and what i need to do is basically only get the xml part of the returned data and set it to a seperate variable i guess. So for example

```
  array(
    ['name']='john',
    ['location']='california',
  )

  <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <data>
       <name>somename</name>

    </data>

   array(
    ['name']='john',
    ['location']='california',
  )

  array(
    ['name']='john',
    ['location']='california',
  )
```

and so i only want the XML part of this entire data. I haven't tried anything because I dont even know where to begin can someone help me out please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = "
  array(
    ['name']='john',
    ['location']='california',
  )

  <?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
     <data>
       <name>somename</name>

    </data>

   array(
    ['name']='john',
    ['location']='california',
  )

  array(
    ['name']='john',
    ['location']='california',
  )
";

$matches = array();
preg_match('/<\?xml(.*)<\/data>/is', $result, $matches);

var_dump(reset($matches));
```

Comment: @Yevo Is the closing tag always going to be `</data>`?

Answer (score 4):

As a prelude, it's important to note that whatever you are doing, this is almost certainly the wrong way to go about it. You should try and manipulate the application producing this data so that it produces the data in a rigidly defined format.

For the purposes of this answer, I shall assume that is not possible in this case.

---

Pretty obviously the answer to this is to use a regular expression to extract the XML from the rest of the data.

But both the other answers that attempt to provide this regular expression aren't nearly good enough for the generic use case. Here's what I would do:

```
@
    (?:<\?xml.*?\?>\s*)?             # optionally match the XML declaration
    <([^/]\S*)[^>]*>                 # match opening tag and capture the tag name
    (?:                              # group alternates together
        (?>                          # atomic group for efficiency
            (?:(?!</?[^/>]+[^/]>).)+ # match everything up to the next long tag
        )
      | (?R)                         # ...or a recursive match of the expression
    )*                               # ...zero or more times
    </\1>                            # match the closing tag
@isx
```

This, crucially, assumes that the XML you are looking for is well formed. It is important to note that you should not, and to a large extend *can*not use regular expressions for this task unless you are 100% certain the XML you are searching for is well formed.

If that is the case, this expression will match any complete XML document nested within a given string, and is able to cope with traps like elements who's tag name match the document element and self-closing tags.

[See it working](http://codepad.viper-7.com/WDAJ94)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately I cannot modify the data being sent but I understand what your saying. Also the xml does have to be correct format because I am eventually going to use simplexml so it has go be formatted correct thank you.

Comment: can you please explain what you have written as far as the regex goes. All i see is a bunch of regex patterns not really usefull when i dont know where to put it

Comment: @Yevo Have you had a look at the link at the very end of the post? That should demonstrate how to get a string containing just the XML document from the variable containing the raw source data.

Comment: Sorry didnt notice that. Thank you. When i take you example with the code it works but when i plug it into my example doesnt seem to work. It may be due to the fact that i have more tags in the xml then what i showed in this post. Would that affect the code you wrote or would it automatically take as many attributes and children in the xml and work regardless

Comment: @Yevo Can you show a sample of your real data e.g. on http://pastebin.com/ so I can have a play with it? This *should* match any XML, although I have realised it may not be able to cope with CDATA and I will update it shortly

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a regular expression to detect the XML header (`<?xml version="1.0"?>`) and the root element (`<data>`).  Once you have that, you just need to detect, the closing tag (`</data>`) and voila!  Wheat separated from chaff!

Comment: Thank you. Do you by any chance have any code that you can share I can begin with? Im not the biggest fan of regex